# Bootstrap Select Menu - Add New Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple Bootstrap form with a select input:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="category" class="control-label col-sm-3">Category</label>
  <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
      <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
      <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The users now have a requirement to be able to add a new option dynamically to the select menu rather than be restricted to the items on the select menu.

I'm not sure if it's possible to modify a select menu and how to make it consistent with the rest of the Bootstrap framework?

Comment: You use JavaScript to dynamically add an `<option>` element to the `select`.  What have you tried?  Post what you are having problems with and maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an option dynamically, there should be a UI button giving you that choice. To get user input, we can use the `window.prompt` method.

We then create an option element, set its value attribute and set its name. Then just append these elements and nodes to the DOM with `appendChild`

Try playing around with this. I added some items like Steak, potatoes and beer.

```js
var addOption = document.getElementById("add-option");
var selectField = document.getElementById("category");
addOption.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var item = prompt("What would you like");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", item);
    var optionName = document.createTextNode(item);
    option.appendChild(optionName);
    selectField.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="category" class="control-label col-sm-3">Category</label>
  <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
      <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
      <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add-option" class="btn btn-primary">Add a new option</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

some select

```
<select id="region" class="selectpicker">
        <option>region 1</option>
        <option>region 2</option>
        <option>region 3</option>
</select>
```

jquery js

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
$("#region").on('change', function () {
   $(this)
       .append('<option>region4</option><option>region5</option>')
       .selectpicker('refresh');
});
```